# ReSharper && StyleCop?

Tags: resharper, stylecop

I have a really simple question. Is the intention to run both StyleCop AND ReSharper?

StyleCop provides code analysis, but so does Re-Sharper...are they really both necessarry?

Thanks in advance
Al

Answer (score 4):

StyleCop only analyses your code style (stuff like formatting). ReSharper doesn't have so many analyses for code style. For example, it doesn't highlight wrong formatting (but you can run Code Cleanup tool in ReSharper which would simply reformat your code and get rid of all formatting problems).

Instead, ReSharper has many analyses for potential errors or possible improvements in your code. StyleCop can't do that.

By the way, StyleCop is mostly used as a plugin for ReSharper. So you can just install both and see for yourself.